# Update image tags using entity metadata wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to bulk update image tags using `entity_metadata_wrapper`.

I'm unable to see the image field when I use `$emw->getPropertyInfo()`.

The bundle is called `hub_page`.

The code I'm using is:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node_id, array('bundle' => 'hub_page'));
var_dump($wrapper->getPropertyInfo());
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You must pass in a node object as the second value, instead of a node ID.

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node, ['bundle' => 'hub_page']);
```

That might be your problem. Check out the docs: [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers).

Comment: Thank @leymannx I'm using the node object but still not seeing the fields I'm expecting.